# How to read docker json log files in a readable format?

Tags: linux, docker, logging, json

I always back up docker json log files when I deploy a new image version.

Is there a linux program or command that lets me browse the log output from backed-up json log files in a readable format like when you use "docker logs"?

or a broader question: what's a good way to deal with docker logging that lets me easily look at logs from depricated images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general purpose tool for working with JSON from CLI, called `jq`. It's pretty powerful, allowing filtering and selecting specific fields among others.